# Fluent Security - configuring parameterized controller actions

Tags: c#, fluent-security

I have done quite a bit of research and have tested both the 1.4 and 2.0 versions of the FluentSecurity libraries and I don't seem to be able to use the configuration pattern:

```
configuration.For<MyController>(x => x.GetCustomer())
  .RequireRole(appRoles);
```

when my controller action requires a parameter such as:

```
public ActionResult GetCustomer(int customerID)
```

Is this type of configuration currently supported?  If so, how do I implement a role requirement against an action that has a required parameter?

Answer (score 2):

I was asking the same question. Currently, you can pass in default values for the parameters.

```
configuration
    .For<HomeController>(x => x.Index(default(string)))
    .DenyAnonymousAccess();
```

where `HomeController` is:

```
public ActionResult Index(string id)
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: I recommend using the simplest thing possible. As the value is completely ignored you can pass it values like "", 0 or false. Whatever feels best in your case.