# How can I configure Fluent Security policies for methods that take parameters?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, lambda, compiler-errors, fluent-security

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fluent Security - configuring parameterized controller actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13203875/fluent-security-configuring-parameterized-controller-actions)

I'm trying out Fluent Security to enforce security policies in an ASP.NET MVC application, but I can't define policies for controller methods that take parameters. As an example of what I mean, the following code snippet shows the controller that should be secured:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    ...

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult LogOff()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Disassociate(string provider, string providerUserId)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

And, this code snippet shows (conceptually) how I'm trying to configure Fluent Security to allow authenticated access to the two controller methods.

```
SecurityConfigurator.Configure(config => {
    config.For<AccountController>().DenyAuthenticatedAccess();
    config.For<AccountController>(x => x.LogOff()).DenyAnonymousAccess();
    config.For<AccountController>(x => x.Disassociate()).DenyAnonymousAccess();
});
```

The latter code won't build however, due to there being no arguments to `Disassociate`. The compiler reports the following: `No overload for method 'Disassociate' takes 0 arguments`.

How do I configure Fluent Security for the method `AccountController.Disassociate(string, string)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you can pass any value(s) of the expected type(s), so in my case I can do the following just to appease the compiler:

```
config.For<AccountController>(x => x.Disassociate("", "")).DenyAnonymousAccess();
```